# Android Retrofit 2: Random code 400 (bad request) response

Tags: android, retrofit2, bad-request

I am using Retrofit to upload files to a server. It works correctly sometimes, but occasionally (and quite often), it gives me response 400 (Bad request) to the same request. Is it a known issue or what could be the problem?

This is whole code for upload:

```
public static void uploadFile(String authString,
                              Uri fileUri,
                              Context context,
                              MVPCallback<ResponseBody> mvpCallback) {
    FileUploadService service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class, authString);
    String filePath = FacadeMedia.getPath(context, fileUri);
    if (filePath != null) {
        File uploadFile = new File(filePath);
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(context.getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                        uploadFile);
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", uploadFile.getName(), requestFile);
        String content_disposition = "file; filename=\"" + uploadFile.getName() + "\"";
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(body, content_disposition);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                                   Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    mvpCallback.onSuccess(response.body());
                }else {
                    mvpCallback.onError(new Throwable(response.errorBody().toString()));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                mvpCallback.onError(t);
            }
        });
    }
}


public interface FileUploadService {

@Multipart
@POST(HttpFactory.UPLOAD_FILE_URL)
Call<ResponseBody> upload(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
        @Header("Content-Disposition") String content_disposition
);
}


public class ServiceGenerator {

private static Retrofit retrofit;

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
        new OkHttpClient.Builder();

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String authString)     {
    httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", " Basic "+authString).build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });
    retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

}

EDIT:

This is the errorBody message:

```
E/Bad request:: <html>
            <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
            <body bgcolor="white">
            <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
            <hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: have you check in which case the error getting?

Comment: There is no rule. It just happens. Sometimes it starts working after 4-5 consequent attempt, sometimes I have to restart the app and it still won't work, sometimes it will.

Comment: is it getting sucess response in any case?

Comment: HTTP errors are issued by the server. You could start investigating there (especially if the exactly same request sometimes gives an error and sometimes not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed this my reinitializing OkHttpClient every ew request. Probably it has some old data in it. If anyone can elaborate on this, would be great.

Comment: try this rule in your header: "Cache-Control: no-cache"

Comment: I am having the same problem. My retrofit library version is 1.9. When i hit an api with HttpUrlConnection it goes through perfectly, so SSL should not a problem. Still i will mention that i am using Letsencrypt. Even with postman and python requests it is working. But whenever i hit any api with retrofit it gives 400 Bad Request and returns and html data. Any help?